# Read data from Access Database into listbox

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datareader

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, conn)
 --> conn: Aurgument type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\KevinDW\\Desktop\\dotNET\\Week 5\\Prak1\\demo1.accdb";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

        conn.Open();

        string sqlCmd = "SELECT CursusNaam FROM tblCursus";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, conn);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(reader);
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change SqlCommand with OleDbCommand class.

Comment: OleCommand and OleDataReader to go with OleDbConnection

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Sql and OleDb

Use `OleDbCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`
and use `OleDBDataReader` instead of `SqlDataReader`

**For example:**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\KevinDW\\Desktop\\dotNET\\Week 5\\Prak1\\demo1.accdb";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

        conn.Open();

        string sqlCmd = "SELECT CursusNaam FROM tblCursus";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd, conn);

        using (OleDBDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(reader);
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SqlCommand/etc which requires the use of SqlConnection object instead of OleDbConnection.

Is it a SQL database you are connecting to? If so use `SqlConnection` instead

Edit: Obviously not, reading the connection string ... :D